# how to check validation of csv file with two fields

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, csv

I have simple csv file that should contain only two non-empty fields as the following

**This is example of right csv file**

```
$ more file.csv    
why_we_need_help,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,log_low=53687091200
.
.
.
```

The target is to check if the csv file contains only two non-empty fields.

I start with the following awk to check if file has only two fields

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=2{print "not enough fields" }' file.csv
```

But it does not give “not enough fields” in this example below, which is not OK.

```
why_we_need_help,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,
```

Example of other wrong csv files:

```
why_we_need_help,,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200,
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,log_low=53687091200,
```

or

```
why_we_need_help log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,,
```

Comment: Do you want the error message printed for every malformed line of the file (your `awk` example would do that), or only once at end-of-file? Also, can there be empty lines in your file? Does your `awk` command incorrectly print the error message for the "correct csv file" you show at the beginning of your question? If not, can you include an example for a correct file which is incorrectly labelled as having the wrong number of fields?

Comment: Do you want the error message printed for every malformed line of the file - yes you can , but mode important is just the output of ok/fail

Comment: no empty lines in the file

Comment: My problem is that if I apply your `awk` code to your "right csv file" example, it correctly gives no error output. I see that it incorrectly assesses your second "wrong csv" example as correct, but this is because an empty field is still counted as field. Can you show where your code says the file is wrong even though it is ok?

Comment: my code is wrong , and in case the second field is empty then status should be failed

Comment: I repeat again about what I need - status should be ok only if we have two fields and both fields are not empty , and each line include two sepertaors - ","

Comment: I understand that - the only thing I didn't understand was that you wrote your code gives "not enough fields even if file is ok". If I try your code, it never prints that if the file is ok.

Comment: *The statement in the question is wrong*. It reads " `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=2{print "not enough fields" }' file.csv` but give “not enough fields” even file is ok". You are saying here in the comments that it does not print the message if the file is not OK. Please, make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} f{skip} NF!=2||!length($1)||!length($2){f=1} END{if (f) {print "File contains malformed lines"; exit 1}}' file.csv
```

If will set a flag `f` whenever a file doesn't contain two `,`-separated fields or any of the two required fields is empty. In the end, it prints a message if the flag was set while parsing the file, and exits with error code 1 (as per your request).

The first rule skips parsing the line if the flag was already set, to speed up the process, since you only want to know if there is any one malformed line - so once such a line was found, we know that the file is malformed and don't need to consider the rest of the file.

In case you want to know how many lines were malformed, this small change would print it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=2||!length($1)||!length($2){f++} END{if (f) {printf("File contains %d malformed line(s)\n",f); exit 1}}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Another awk option is

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NF!=2||$1==""||$2==""{print "Not enough fields";exit 5}' file.csv
```

It checks explicitly if any of the two fields is empty. If so, it prints the message and immediately exits with error code 5 (this number is arbitrary, choose the one you like most).

Comment: `print "Invalid line: " NR` might be helpful to pinpoint the line with the invalid fields.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I THINK what you're looking for is:

```
awk -F',' 'NF!=2 || /^,|,$/{print "bad:", NR | "cat>&2"; exit 1}' file
```

which could be improved to report the specific error(s) on the line:

```
awk -F',' '
    NF<2 { err="too few fields" }
    NF>2 { err="too many fields" }
    /^,|,$/ { err=(err == "" ? "" : err " and ") "empty fields" }
    err != "" { print err, "at line", NR | "cat>&2"; exit 1 }
' file
```

or if you want all errors on all lines found at once:

```
awk -F',' '
    NF<2 { err="too few fields" }
    NF>2 { err="too many fields" }
    /^,|,$/ { err=(err == "" ? "" : err " and ") "empty fields" }
    err != "" { print err, "at line", NR | "cat>&2"; err=""; f=1 }
    END { exit f }
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small function that uses grep. Its exit code will be 0 when no lines are invalid and will be 1 if at least 1 line is invalid (in which case, the first invalid line is printed and processing is aborted - no further lines are checked).

The *regexp* used means **at the beginning of the line, one or more characters that aren't a comma, followed by 1 comma, followed by one or more characters that aren't a comma, and then nothing else**.

```
lines_are_valid() {
  grep -E -m1 -v '^[^,]+,[^,]+$' && return 1 || return 0
}
```

How to use it:

```
cat myFile | lines_are_valid
```

More examples:

```
echo 'this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,' \
| lines_are_valid \
  && echo "All lines OK" \
  || echo "Invalid line found, see above"
```

> look_on_the_room,
>
> Invalid line found, see above

```
echo 'this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,aaa' \
| lines_are_valid \
  && echo "All lines OK" \
  || echo "Invalid line found, see above"
```

> All lines OK

```
echo 'this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,,
also wrong,' \
| lines_are_valid \
  && echo "All lines OK" \
  || echo "Invalid line found, see above"
```

> look_on_the_room,,
>
> Invalid line found, see above

```
echo 'this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,,asdfasdf
also wrong,' \
| lines_are_valid \
  && echo "All lines OK" \
  || echo "Invalid line found, see above"
```

> look_on_the_room,,asdfasdf
>
> Invalid line found, see above

In case you want to show all invalid lines:

```
show_all_invalid_lines() {
  grep -E -v '^[^,]+,[^,]+$' && return 1 || return 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, updated!

Answer (score -1):

Inputfile

```
 cat op.txt 
why_we_need_help,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,log_low=53687091200
look_on_the_room, 
   ,ajay
```

Awk command

```
awk -F "," 'NF == "2" {print $0}' filename | sed "s/,/ /g"| sed -n '/\s\{2,\}/!p'| awk '{gsub(" ",",",$0);print}'
```

output

```
why_we_need_help,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,log_low=53687091200
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
u=re.compile(r' {2,}')
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    q=re.sub(","," ",i)
    if not  re.search (u,q):
        print q.replace(" ",",").strip()
```

output

```
why_we_need_help,log_low=53687091200
whats_is_going_on,log_high=1073741824
this_is_caryze,log_low=53687091200
let_me_know_what_to_do,log_high=1073741824
look_on_the_room,log_low=53687091200
```

Comment: I'm afraid your `awk|sed|sed|awk` code is trying to remove invalid lines from the input file, which is not what the OP wanted - the OP wanted to _detect_ them and return with an error status if found. Also, the `awk` example only removes lines which have the wrong number of `,` separators; it doesn't detect if any of the fields is empty, which the OP also wanted to make sure. You could also make your code more efficient by doing everything in `awk` instead of the multi-pipeline-construct.

Comment: will try to improve my code